# Magento: Buy 3 pay for 2 does not work for me

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3, coupon-codes

I like to set a "Buy 3 pay for 2" item rule. I have created a "Cart Price Rules" but it does not seem to apply.

If I add 3 of the same items or 3 different items it still results in the original price.

What am I doing wrong? the changes does not show at all.

[image: Promo rule does not work 3 for 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this function does not exist as standard in Magento. Instead I bought a plugin for it.

the built in support requires that all the products are the same.

Instead I bought this one:
https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html

Comment: I think it does now. I added the URL where I bought the plugin needed to solve the problem. Magento does not support this functionality at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

try to put 1 in Discount amount, as this is the quantity the customer will receive for free. Plus, clear cache and perform re-index after the rule is created.

Comment: Sadly it did not work :(